# Help wanted with regular expression

Tags: php, regex

I would like to parse a mailer to-string which could consist of the following examples separated with a comma (,):

```
First name <email@example.com>
"first name" <email@example.com>
<email@example.com>
email@example.com
```

I would like to make an array with an entry for each element with two sub-entries: [name] and [email].

I've been struggling with the regexp for (what looks like) ages.  Could someone help me?

Comment: To make a regexp easier, you could analyze it line by line in a loop, then each regexp could look like /(["\w\s]+)?\s?<?(\w+\@\w+\.\w+)>?/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the imap extension enabled, it may be as simple as:

```
var_dump(imap_rfc822_parse_adrlist('First name <email@example.com>,
    "first name" <email@example.com>,
    <email@example.com>,
    email@example.com','_invalid_'));
```

Output:

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  object(stdClass)#1 (3) {
    ["mailbox"]=>
    string(5) "email"
    ["host"]=>
    string(11) "example.com"
    ["personal"]=>
    string(10) "First name"
  }
  [1]=>
  object(stdClass)#2 (3) {
    ["mailbox"]=>
    string(5) "email"
    ["host"]=>
    string(11) "example.com"
    ["personal"]=>
    string(10) "first name"
  }
  [2]=>
  object(stdClass)#3 (2) {
    ["mailbox"]=>
    string(5) "email"
    ["host"]=>
    string(11) "example.com"
  }
  [3]=>
  object(stdClass)#4 (2) {
    ["mailbox"]=>
    string(5) "email"
    ["host"]=>
    string(11) "example.com"
  }
}
```

Comment: The regex for parsing email addresses that comply with with the rfc822 spec is a bit complex. http://www.ex-parrot.com/pdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html +1

Comment: @Buggabill The regexp wouldn't actually need to validate the e-mail address, just find it within the main string, which isn't particularly difficult